# Is it possible to train a model Tensorflow Object Detection API with Tensorflow 2.1?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.x

When training the model Tensorflow Object Detection API on Tensorflow-gpu 2.1, there is an error:

**No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'**

Is it possible to train a model Tensorflow Object Detection API with Tensorflow 2.1?
I dont want to change the version of Tensorflow.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi Norbert Uefa, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code? or a link reference?

Comment: These days it was announced that Object Detection API is supported by TF 2: [link](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/07/tensorflow-2-meets-object-detection-api.html).

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow object detection API currently works only for Tensorflow 1.x (>=1.12.0), but it's in the works.

See this Github thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6423.